# Mysql limit when the whole list may change

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that returns 10 items of a big list. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE user_is_block = 0
AND user_is_paid = 1
ORDER BY user_post_hour ASC, id ASC"
```

When I put `limit ?, ?` to get a part of this list each time, a problem happens. Imagine we get the first 10. The row with id 11, is the first one in the next request. But as we use `ORDER BY user_post_hour`, the id 11 may go up and become 10. So when second request is sent, we never see id 11.

Any idea?

Comment: Consider returning the entire dataset to your application layer, as json or (if you're a bit old-fashioned) xml, say. Then just paginate that result set.

Comment: what is data type for "user_post_hour" .

Comment: @Strawberry That's of course json. But the problem is that the list (table) is big and for each row I should run another query, and it may take a lot of time.

Comment: @Santosh That is integer.

Comment: But if you do it the way I suggest, then it's only one query

Comment: try with explicitly casting in order by.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the problem with datatype soring, again cast your column value to an integer explicitly

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE user_is_block = 0
AND user_is_paid = 1
ORDER BY cast(user_post_hour as unsigned) ASC, id ASC
```

Use this trick.

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE user_is_block = 0
AND user_is_paid = 1
ORDER BY user_post_hour+0 ASC, id ASC
```

Comment: I didn't understand what it does with `LIMIT`! Look, the problem is the list may change in each request. The number 11 in my rows, may become 10 in second query, so it will never come back to client.